# Garbage collector in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

//Java Code..

```
class X2 
{
    public X2 x;
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        X2 x2 = new X2();   /* Line 6 */
        X2 x3 = new X2();   /* Line 7 */
        x2.x = x3;
        x3.x = x2;
        x2 = new X2();
        x3 = x2;           /* Line 11 */
        doComplexStuff();
    }
}
```

After line no:11 runs How many object are eligible for garbage collection?
Please give me link to understand this concept properly.

Comment: I think this exact question was asked a few days ago (and removed).

Comment: A classic exam/interview question. Not real programming.

Comment: Tell us what you think and we'll discuss it.

Comment: Since `doComplexStuff()` could do anything, this question has no definite answer.  Alternative answer: `doComplexStuff` is an unknown symbol => compilation error => zero objects created in the first place.  :-)

Comment: All the objects you no longer have a reference to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two, potentially all three of them. Since the local variables are not used after line 11 the [JVM is free to set them to `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1), and they become eligible for garbage collection. From JLS 12.6.1:

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.

This can be observed to happen in practice on the Hotspot JVM (see for example [The JVM ate my variable!](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/can-your-interpreter-do-this/)).

Comment: Yes, the answer is "it depends."

Answer (score 1):

Two of them.

```
x2 = new X2();
```

makes the previous connection redundant. If `x2` is used nowhere else, then the connection will be lost and the garbage collector will remove it from the memory.

```
x3 = x2;
```

This points `x3` to `x2`, thus omitting the former value of x3. This will also be cleaned by the garbage collector if it isn't used anywhere else.